# Will my 2010 tfs build scripts work with 2013 build controller?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

I have build scripts which work with 2010.
Will these work with 2013 build controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2010 Build Controller and Build Agents work with TFS 2013.  If you're concerned about compatibility, you can just leave your build servers running the 2010 Build components.

Comment: Can the 2010 Build Controllers be configure to point to the VSO?

Answer (score 1):

The XAML Build templates are platform specific and will only work with their version of TFS.

If you have MS Build scripts or use another make platform scripts then you should be able to call them from any platform.

You can always as Dylan sugests continue to use your 2010 controllers.

Comment: My DefaultTemplate.xaml from TFS 2010 works fine running on TFS 2013.  They are not version-specific in my experience.